# How can I prevent Intellij IDEA to reparse my code at each keystroke?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I write Java code in the IntelliJ IDEA IDE and it seems to me that each time I hit a key it reparses (evaluates) my whole sources.

To be clear, when I want to write this:

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
         System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

and I am at this point ([CARET/CURSOR] = position of current):

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
         System.out.prin[CARET/CURSOR]
    }
}
```

IDEA alraedy tells me already the helpful message:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'prin'.';' expected

I have tried very hard to get IDEA not to do this (as obviously while I still type the source line,I do not want this unfinished work to be compiled/evaluate)

How can I get IDEA to not do this? Not only do those idioticly pointless message disturb, they are also making typing a pain, as the responsiveness is nil, while the CPU searches the unfinished code.

**Addition/Update**
This picture below illustrates the problem, i.e. that the inspection is rerun at each keystroke:

[image: idea reparses the entered test at each keystroke]

In the mean time I have used an open source Java profiler https://visualvm.github.io/, available form my distro's package manager. Which has (as suggested in the comments) helped in finding out, that the delay and slowness incurred to inspection, is not the parsing in the first place, but rather the yet imperfect wayland linux display server support of IntelliJ, which recurring to an indirection via Xwayland, has slowed down the delay between "finger hits key" to "glyph is added to source" to unbearable limits.

Comment: You can go to menu File -> Power Save Mode. This may help.

Comment: @m0skit0 quite the inverse, because I'd like to be able to type fast, it is extremely disturbing to have the lag between hitting the keys and having seein an immediate result on the screen. Your suggestion, no offence indented, seems arrogant and not helpful.

Comment: There should be no lag with typing at all caused by the analysis, if you have lag, you should report an issue with the [CPU snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235) attached. See this post about the [Zero Latency Typing](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/08/experimental-zero-latency-typing-in-intellij-idea-15-eap/). This option is enabled by default in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.

Comment: I meant no offense, sorry. I don't have these issues and my computer is fairly old, nor I have seen anyone have such issues. There are no suggestions when I'm typing, and certainly no slow response. Can you record what is happening to you?

Comment: @m0skit0 I will try to record it, thanks. Why using IDE, provides the features refactoring, and decompiling (of JAVA jars), and debuging.

Comment: @CrazyCoder the snapshot would need to be created with a proprietary closed source application from https://www.yourkit.com/download/ not included with intellij IDEA. Any other profiler possible, for such a CPU snapshot?

Comment: Profiler agent is included with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate versions, for CE versions the agent can be downloaded for free, it's described in the document I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

The Inspection feature of the IntelliJ IDEA IDE, can be adjusted at different places within the IDE. The comment by @MonteChristo with turning on `File -> Power Save Mode` has indeed already led into the right direction, to prevent IntelliJ IDEA from parsing the code at each keystroke.

There is however another setting which can be found as illustrated here:

- [image: the location of the quick setting for inspections in IntelliJ IDEA]

where then it is possible to swiftly reduce or inhibit inspection alltogether, using this settings menu.

- [image: the quick setting for inspections in IntelliJ IDEA]

As visible the connection to `power save mode` which is maybe the quickest workaround persists.

Also please note that even though inspection gets disabled, results from previous inspection runs (i.e. red underlines, red text) will remain.

It seems to me that according to my test only the setting `power save mode` was really able to completely disable the parsing at each keystroke, while all other settings kept the code parsed at each keystroke.